# Trying to delete all the contents in table

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to solve why my code isn't working. Tip is preciated. I'm also wondering, when this works, will the Primary key, in this case, the ID columns also reset and start all over from 1?

```
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        sql = "DELETE * From Guests";
        sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        sqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the asterisk

```
DELETE FROM Guests
```

To reset the primary key, use

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Guests
```

And you want

```
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

not `EndExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: Thanks, but I have tested it without the *, but that don't seem to be the problem!

Comment: @3D-kreativ You have to use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `EndExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I picked wrong from the proposals in Visual Studio!

Comment: So TRUNCATE TABLE Guests will both erase and reset primary key then?

Comment: Yes. Unless you have relationships defined against the Guests table

Comment: Also be advised truncate requires an elevated privilege than the delete.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the "*". The correct syntax for a delete statement is:

```
delete from Guests
```

You should also get into the habit of using "using" for disposable types, like SqlConnection and SqlCommand. Like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    string sql = "DELETE From Guests";
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have tested it without the *, but that don't seem to be the problem!